# How to automate operations between each columns of two matrices using R?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, lapply, sapply

I have general function written for MAPE (mean absolute percentage error)

```
mape <- function(y, yhat)
     mean(abs((y - yhat)/y))
```

I want to calculate MAPE between each column of two different matrices. 
Suppose they are in following format

```
y = matrix(c(11, 12, 12, 12, 14, 16, 23, 21, 28),byrow=TRUE,ncol=3)
```

and predicted as

```
yp = matrix(c(12, 13, 14, 12, 15, 17, 24, 22, 28),byrow=TRUE,ncol=3)
```

This can be manually done for each column as `mape(y[,1],yp[,1])`

How do I automate such process (any other operation also - not only MAPE) of performing operations between each columns of large dimension matrix using R? can FOR loops be avoided using apply/sapply?

Comment: If the alternative is to use `apply` or `sapply` you can safely use `for` loops without basically any downside. You won't speed up  things  replacing a loop with an `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update:

Of course mape can be vectorised:

```
mapeVec <- function(y, yhat)
  colMeans(abs((y-yhat)/y))

f3 <- function() { mapeVec(y, yp) } 

Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 f1() 33.677431 34.121107 35.494355 34.441823 35.078125 46.16782   100  b 
 f2() 33.558224 33.970123 35.609414 34.239525 34.881354 49.99195   100  b 
 f3()  8.344952  8.525146  9.218695  8.568763  8.709681 17.82791   100 a  

identical(f1(), f3())  # TRUE
```

#### Old part:

`sapply` with a sequence `seq(nrow(y))` should do the trick:

```
mape <- function(y, yhat)
  mean(abs((y - yhat)/y))

y <- matrix(c(11, 12, 12, 12, 14, 16, 23, 21, 28), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

yp = matrix(c(12, 13, 14, 12, 15, 17, 24, 22, 28), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

sapply(seq(nrow(y)), function(id) { mape(y[,id], yp[,id]) })
```

#### Microbenchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)

mape <- function(y, yhat)
  mean(abs((y - yhat)/y))

y <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), nrow = 1000, ncol = 1000)

yp = matrix(rnorm(1000000), nrow = 1000, ncol = 1000)

f1 <- function() { sapply(seq(nrow(y)), function(id) { mape(y[,id], yp[,id]) }) }

f2 <- function() { 
  a <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nrow(y))
  for(id in seq(nrow(y))) { 
    a[id] <- mape(y[,id], yp[,id]) 
  }
  a
}

microbenchmark(
  f1(),
  f2()
)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 f1() 33.28310 34.15209 36.57389 35.42845 36.20803 48.11936   100   a
 f2() 34.14755 34.78859 37.65782 36.33395 37.06874 64.10664   100   a
```

#### Personal comment:

`f1` (`sapply()` approach) looks much more compact and "clean".

Comment: You could replace `seq(1:dim(y)[1])` with `seq(nrow(y))`. It doesn't change anything, just makes it a little more apparent where the length comes from.

Comment: Replaced. Could not resist: `microbenchmark( seq(1:dim(y)[1]), seq(nrow(y)), times = 1000 )` gives `10.82` vs `9.88` means and `9.87` vs `8.69` medians.

Comment: That is because you use `seq(1:dim(y)[1])`, i.e. you sequence essentially twice. If you instead use `seq(dim(y)[1])` you get the exact same results. If you are trying to optimize for speed, use `seq_len` instead.